# VBA photo/image compression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am wondering if this is possible and within the realms of Access?

I currently have a database system where the user can open up directories/folders related to the record; such as images, docs etc...
This avoids bloat by attaching the images to the records and what not, and works fine.

A user enhancement would be to allow the user to automatically compress photos so that they are more appropriate in file size to attach to emails.

I was wondering if it would be possible to, say whilst using the FileSystemObject and CopyFile, copy the photos from one folder (/photos) to another folder (/compressed_photos) and compress them at the same time.

Could I use "VBA.Shell" and run a batch image compression program on the photos?

Any advice on the above is greatly appreciated, even if it is just to confirm that it is not possible.

Cheers
Noel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [ImageMagick via Command Line](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). See the examples on the manual pages there.

Comment: Cheers tom, ill have a look at that and using the command line in VBA

Comment: +1 But he might prefer using ImageMagickObject from VBA rather than going through Shell: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php

Comment: ImageMagickObject is the way to go, added the "ImageMagickObject Type Library 1.0" and can convert the images, brilliant and quite simple in the end. Thanks Tom & HansUp